# Invalid hook call inside React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using typescript and simply using a hook inside `React.FC` but I'm getting error saying I can only use hooks inside functional components. `React.FC` doens't count as a funcional component?

Here is what I'm doing

```
interface Props { }

export const Register: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      Register View
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the error

[image]

> ×
> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This
> could happen for one of the following reasons:
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

This makes no sense, how is this possible? If I remove the line `const [test, setTest] = useState('')`, everything works normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use hooks in a functional component that you render with jsx I guess you try to render the functional component with `{Register(props)}` but you should render it with `<Register {...props}>`.

Answer (score 0):

HMR is correct, I figure  out that the problem was on how I was creating the routes.

I was using `render`, which do something like `Register(props)`

```
<Route exact path='/register' render={Register} />
```

But I should be using `component` for `<Register {...props}>` to be created

```
<Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
```